# Reading date and time from text file

Tags: datetime, gnuplot

I'm getting confused trying to read a date and time for gnuplot from a text file. The file looks like this:

03.07.2022,13:40:18,119.5,119.5,119.5,17.5,60.00,100.0,27.27,35.1,
03.07.2022,13:30:18,119.5,119.5,119.5,17.5,60.00,100.0,27.27,35.5,
03.07.2022,13:20:18,119.5,119.5,119.5,17.5,60.00,100.0,27.27,35.5,

Here are the relevant lines from my script:

set timefmt "%d.%m.%Y,%H:%M:%S"

plot 'data-nohead.txt' using ($1):2

This gives an error:

"./plot_voltage.gp" line 35: Can't plot with an empty x range!

I don't use gnuplot often, so sometimes do stupid things. Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You have a tricky case because your file uses a comma both as a field separator and as a component of the time. This means the time information actually spans columns 1 and 2, while the first non-time information is in column 3.  I have added a separate format for the tic labels to confirm that the full time is being read.

```
set datafile separator comma
set timefmt "%d.%m.%Y,%H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
set xtics time format "%d.%m.%Y\n%H:%M"
plot 't.dat' using 1:3
```

[image]